# Duda con async await - chatgpt

Tags: javascript, async

Estoy tratando de conectar ChatGPT con la librería para nodejs openai, la misma me da respuesta positiva, pero cuando intento crear una función basada en async y await, respuesta obtenida es promise...
Quisiera saber cuál podría ser el problema con el mismo.
Anexo el código utilizado.
Muchas gracias

```
const { Configuration, OpenAIApi } = require("openai");
require("dotenv").config();

const configuration = new Configuration({
    apiKey: process.env.API_KEY,
});

const openai = new OpenAIApi(configuration);

async function doStuff(x) {
    const completion = await openai.createCompletion({
      model: "text-davinci-002",
      prompt: x,
    });  
    return completion.data.choices[0].text;
  }


console.log(doStuff("Cual es la capital de Alemania ?"));
```

Comment: probaste resolviendo la Promesa y obteniendo su resultado?

Comment: No has probado si en `const completion = await openai.createCompletion({ model: "text-davinci-002", prompt: x, });` te funcione un `.then(completion => { completion.data.choices[0].text; return completion; });` o similar? No se si estoy en lo correcto.

Comment: O también prueba un await en `console.log( await doStuff("Cual es la capital de Alemania ?"));` a ver que se ve.

Answer (score 1):

Cuando utilizas una función asíncrona su retorno será una promesa (`Promise<any>`) y para resolver la promesa utilizas `await`.

Entonces para sacar la respuesta tendría que ser en un entorno `async`. Yo en este caso usaría una función que se llame así misma también conocidas como **Immediately-invoked Function Expression**

```javascript
async function doStuff(x) {
   const completion = await openai.createCompletion({
      model: "text-davinci-002",
      prompt: x,
   });  
   return completion.data.choices[0].text;
}

(async () => {
   const respuesta = await doStuff("Cual es la capital de Alemania ?");
   console.log(respuesta);
})()
```